# VPN and data transfer

Tags: openvpn, isp

I connect from my home computer to our company VPN. Then I login via ssh, from my desktop, to our company server which is actually a Google cloud machine. From the command prompt on that server, I connect to a data provider and ftp/download data files which are many GBs in size (for further processing). Now the question - will this data transfer count towards my Internet connection? My guess is no, since the transfer is between the Google cloud machine and another entity. I just wanted to confirm this before I get hit with a huge bill from my Internet service provider.

Answer (score 2):

From what you said it sounds like your guess is correct. Unless you do something silly like display all the data during the transfer.